# How to enable cards.io in paypal integration in iOS

Tags: ios, paypal, cardio

I have successfully integrated the paypal sdk for iOS. How can i enable cards.io card reader in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. In simulator, it does not show the camera icon. In device it is working fine.

Comment: That's because there isn't a way to easily show the camera in the simulator.